# Is there a name for such series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-progressions

I know a series such as:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} 3i+1 \quad n\in\mathbb{N}$$

Is Arithmetic and has a difference value of $3$.

I also know a series such as:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} {1\over{2^i}} \quad n\in\mathbb{N}$$

Is Geometric and has a common ratio of $1\over 2$.

But what about a series like this?
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} {i\over{2^i}}  \quad n\in\mathbb{N}$$

Is there any name for such type of series?
If so, does it follow any type of pattern/law such as the difference value and the common ratio?

Comment: See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico-geometric_sequence).

Comment: @Eclipse Sun - Thank you :) ...this helped me out a lot.